# Nginx/Flask/Python App, Nginx throwing 502 Bad Gateway Error

Tags: python, nginx, flask

`Nginx` was working fine before, then I added a `form` to my `html` and nginx started throwing this error:

```
2016/12/12 16:37:24 [error] 983#0: *3 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: site.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: "site.com"
```

My **forms.py** looks like:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextField, StringField, SubmitField, validators

class EmailForm(FlaskForm):
  email = TextField("Email")
  submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

my **app.py** looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from forms import EmailForm

app.config['DEBUG'] = True

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secrets'

# add mail server config
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'site.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'contact@site.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'pass'

mail = Mail(app)

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def email():
    form = EmailForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate() == False:
            return 'Please fill in all fields <p><a href="/">Try Again</a></p>'
        else:
            msg = Message("Message from your visitor",
                          sender='contact@site.com',
                          recipients=['contact@site.com'])
           msg.body = """
            From: %s <%s>,
            %s
            """ % (form.email.data)
            mail.send(msg)
            return "Successfully  sent message!"
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**index.html** (in `templates/`):

```
        <form action="{{ url_for('email') }}" method="post">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.email }}
            {{ form.submit }}
        </form>
```

**nginx config in `sites-enabled/`:**

```
server {
   server_name mysite.com;
   listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/www/flask-deploy/mysite/static/;
    }
}
```

I've looked tirelessly at this, but cant seem to pinpoint the problem. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: we need the relevant parts of your nginx config...

Comment: see above please @StephaneMartin

Comment: nginx says it does not find anybody who listens on localhost port 8001. You have an indentation problem after `msg.body="""`. So maybe your python script is not running at all ?

Comment: That is just the way it pasted. I verified that `msg.body` information is on the same line

Comment: and port 8001 ? in flask the default is 5000

Comment: how can i verify the port

Comment: just run manually python app.py, it displays "Running on...". Flask port is configured through app.config['SERVER_NAME'] (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/config/)

Comment: if i run `python app.py` i get 
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 115-763-111

Comment: I got it to work! If you post as an answer, ill gladly accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Connection refused" means that Nginx does not find anything listening on localhost, port 8001. Maybe your flask app is listening on another port. By default flask listens on port 5000.

You could either try:

- to modify nginx conf: `proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;`
- **OR** to make flask app listen on port 8001: `app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = "127.0.0.1:8001"`