# Why I have message 'bad gateway' when I want to access to my web server?

Tags: python, networking

My problem is that I have a python web server for a project, and the goal is that we can can access to this web server with all the computer in the same network. So, my code for my python web server is:

```
from asyncio import tasks
import json
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, url_for, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('task')

class TodoResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'tasks': tasks}

    def post(self):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        task = {'task': args['task']}
        tasks.append(task)
        return task, 201

api.add_resource(TodoResource, '/tasks')

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form
        file_path = "./data.json"
        is_empty_file = not os.path.isfile(file_path) or os.stat(file_path).st_size == 0
        with open(file_path, "a+") as f:
            f.seek(0)
            if not is_empty_file:
                f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
                pos = f.tell() - 1
                while pos > 0 and f.read(1) != "\n":
                    pos -= 1
                    f.seek(pos, os.SEEK_SET)
                if pos > 0:
                    f.seek(pos + 1, os.SEEK_SET)
                else:
                    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)

                f.truncate()
                f.write(",\n")
            else:
                f.write("[\n")
            json.dump(data, f)
            f.write("\n]")

    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/data')
def get_data():
    with open('data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

And when I launch my web server, I should access to my web server with the address: xx.xx.xx.xx:5000 but when I enter this address I opt a message 'bad gateway'.

I ask at chat Gpt but Nothing work

Comment: Have a look at this once https://stackoverflow.com/a/41111140/15358800

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy? Like nginx? How are you launching the webserver? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually one configures a webserver to bridges the connection between your network interface and your Python framework (flask) using the Python Web Server Gateway Interface (in short: WSGI).

If your process is not configured with the correct permissions and access rights, this results in the bad gateway response.

To solve this error, make sure your service is running with the correct permissions and access rights.